# In a rigid body rotating in 3D around the origin, is the norm of the linear velocity of each particle constant?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics

I was trying to prove that kinetic energy is constant in a rigid body undergoing some arbitrary rotation around the origin in a 3D space, and I ended up proving a stronger statement: that the norm of the linear velocity of any one particle is constant.

Is this true?

UPDATE:

I'm assuming the total linear momentum of the body is zero, and therefore its center of mass stays at the origin.

Here is my proof:

Given that the rigid body has some angular velocity $\boldsymbol\omega$, which can also be represented by the skew-symmetric matrix $\bf{W}$, and a particle of the body with position $\bf{x}$, $\bf{v}$, and acceleration $\bf{a}$, I have:

\begin{array}{l}
 {\boldsymbol\omega} \times {\bf{x}} = {\bf{Wx}} \\ 
 {\bf{\dot x}} = {\bf{Wx}} = {\bf{v}} \\ 
 {\bf{\ddot x}} = {\bf{W\dot x}} = {\bf{WWx}} = {\bf{a}} \\ 
 \frac{d}{{dt}}\frac{1}{2}{\bf{v}} \cdot {\bf{v}} = {\bf{v}} \cdot {\bf{a}} = {\bf{x}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{W}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{W\dot x}} = {\bf{x}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{W}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{WWx}} \\ 
 {\bf{W}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{W}} = {\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}} {\boldsymbol\omega\bf{I}} - {\boldsymbol\omega\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}}  \to {\bf{W}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{WW}} = \left( {{\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}} {\boldsymbol\omega\bf{I}} - {\boldsymbol\omega\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}} } \right){\bf{W}} \\ 
 {\bf{x}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{W}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{WWx}} = {\bf{x}}^{\bf{T}} \left( {{\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}} {\boldsymbol\omega\bf{W}} - {\boldsymbol\omega\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{W}}} \right){\bf{x}} = \left\| {\boldsymbol\omega} \right\|^2{\bf{x}}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{Wx}} - {\bf{x}}^{\bf{T}} {\boldsymbol\omega\boldsymbol\omega}^{\bf{T}} {\bf{Wx}} =  \\ 
  = \left( {{\boldsymbol\omega} \cdot {\boldsymbol\omega}} \right)\left( {{\bf{x}} \cdot {\bf{v}}} \right) - \left( {{\bf{x}} \cdot {\boldsymbol\omega}} \right)\left( {{\boldsymbol\omega} \cdot {\bf{v}}} \right) = \left( {{\boldsymbol\omega} \cdot {\boldsymbol\omega}} \right)0 - \left( {{\bf{x}} \cdot {\boldsymbol\omega}} \right)0 = 0 \to \left\| {\bf{v}} \right\| = {\rm{const}} \\ 
 \end{array}

where I use the fact that the particle's linear velocity is orthogonal to both its position as well as its angular velocity.

Comment: If the vector angular velocity changes, this is not true.

Comment: @lpz Thanks for your comment! I've updated my question to include my proof, could I please ask you to have a look and tell me where the error is? Thanks! :)

Comment: @lps Ohhh I think I've assumed that angular acceleration is constant over time, but it's not, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have the velocity field of solid body can be written at every time:
$$
v= v_0+\omega\times r
$$
with $v_0,\omega$ depending a priori with time. In particular, acceleration is:
$$
\dot v = a_0+\dot\omega\times r+\omega\times v
$$
with $a_0 = \dot v_0$.

From this:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2}v^2 &= v\cdot \dot v \\
&= v\cdot (a_0+\dot\omega\times r)
\end{align}
$$
which is in general not zero either when $a_0\neq 0$ or $\dot\omega\neq0$. Since you were implicitly assuming that they were zero, you do indeed obtain conservation of velocity. This is actually obvious, since the motion is uniform rotation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mean to assume constant angular acceleration, just constant angular momentum. I'll try to redo the proof and see what I can get, if I can't do it I'll post another question, hopefully you or someone else might be able to help me :)